# Supervisor not using /etc/environment

Tags: php, environment, supervisord, getenv

I have an script in PHP that prints an environment variable set in /etc/environment with getenv.

It works fine when I execute it manually, but when is executed by supervisor, it doesn't work.

I don't want to put manually this environment variable on supervisor conf file, I want it to read /etc/environment correctly.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As it says in supervisord config files documentation:
[supervisord config documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values)
In the section environment:

> Note that the subprocess will inherit the environment variables of the shell used to start “supervisord” except for the ones overridden here.

I supose that you start supervisord using systemd.
In that case you could check your supervisord.service and in the Service section add:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

After doing a systemctl daemon-reload and systemctl restart supervisord I supose it should work

You could check where is your supervisord.service file using:

```
 systemctl status docker
 docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
```

I have used docker because I have not installed supervisor in my dev machine, but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

getenv gets the value of an environment variable, it doesn't read values from a file. If the environment variable isn't set for your supervisor's session then how can getenv retrieve the value?

From your session, enter the 'set' command. What is the output of that command?
From your supervisor's session, enter the 'set' command? What is the output?

Are you certain that the environment variables for your session are getting set via /etc/environment?

Comment: Environment variables are set by /etc/environment as @olibiaz linked